# no menu in dogecoin-qt wallet client

Tags: 12.04, unity, gui, qt, bitcoin

As you can see, there is no menu on the top menu bar. It says "Dogecoin - Wallet" but there are no "File", "Settings", or "Help" menu titles. Clicking on the word "Dogecoin" in the menu bar or on the top horizontal panel in Unity has no effect.

According to this http://computriks.com/en/bitcoin-encrypt-wallet it seems there should be a menu, albeit that's for a different type of currency.

[image]

see also:

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10482/no-menu-in-ubuntu-bitcoin-qt

Code comes from:

https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin

which is a fork, I believe, of the bitcoin client.  I've tried restarting, but don't see what F2 has to do with it:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ DISPLAY=:0.0 unity --replace
The program 'unity' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install unity
thufir@dur:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the top of the screen (taskbar? area) with the window selected.

[image]

Comment: exactly.  I don't have that. Regardless of mouse over.  That's the question.