# no menu for pan newsreader

Tags: unity, gnome, 16.04, gui, panel

Somewhat similar to:

[no menu in dogecoin-qt wallet client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393875/)

There's no menu for [pan newsreader](http://pan.rebelbase.com/) in a 16.04 install literally days old.  In this case, unity is working, and pan has always worked sufficiently that I expect this is somewhat new.  If this is a duplicate, pardon, a search for "no menu" shows many, many results.

The menu was there yesterday.  I restarted the application, but haven't yet rebooted.

Comment: Perhpas some of these solutions may help: http://askubuntu.com/q/762137/57576

Comment: yes, `initctl restart unity-panel-service` fixed it for me.  bug as per that question.  duplicate question.

Comment: But the good news is that the issue has been at least partially resolved for you :)